# Images in PDF File are distorted when copied to Android

Tags: android, image, pdf

I have a PDF file, when I open it on my computer (Linux) the Images in the PDF file is displayed properly(Its sharp)

But when I copy the same PDF from the computer to Android device and opened it there using Adobe Reader,

It looks like as following,

[image]

What can be the reason for this image distortion. What is the difference in opening this in computer and Android?

Any suggestions can lead me to a better search.

Comment: what is the pdf file size?

Comment: @AkhileshPatil 300 kB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe is the issue, If opened from any other viewer it works